# How to use Ping Federate SAML2.0 with .Net MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, saml, pingfederate

How to use the Ping Federate with MVC application for Single sign On through SAML2.0. Only client side implementation required because we are using existing Ping Federate Identity Provider(IDP) for authenticating the user via SAML.

Answer (score 1):

Another popular approach is to leverage the Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) libraries. Through the web.config, WIF is configured as a WS-Federation connection to PingFederate via the system.identityModel and system.identityModel.services configuration. Then in the application you pick up the identity information via the ClaimsIdentity object.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SAML 2.0 client side stack.

Pick one:

[SAML connectivity toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).